# Ruby: Convert String to Integer values of a nested array

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out why the following expression does not convert Strings to Integers:

```
[["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]].each {|sr| sr.map(&:to_i)}
=> [["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]]
```

So, instead of getting a nested array of integer numbers I'm still getting the same String values. Any idea ?

Thank you.

uSer Ruby version: `2.6.1`

Answer (score 6):

It's because you're using `each`, which returns original array. Use `map` instead:

```
[["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]].map { |sr| sr.map(&:to_i) }
# => [[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

You can also use `map!`, which modifies an array instead of returning a new one, like this:

```
[["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]].each { |sr| sr.map!(&:to_i) }
# => [[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

It depends on what you want, obviously.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marek, for pointing out to what `each` returns as well as to the difference if using the bang `!` version of map in the block.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by @MarekLipka perfectly sheds a light on the issue in pure ruby, I am here to shamelessly promote my gem [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor):

```
[["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]].
  iteraptor.
  map { |_key, value| value.to_i }
#⇒ [[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

or, if you like Spanish:

```
[["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]].mapa { |_, value| value.to_i }
#⇒ [[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

It would work with arrays of any depth:

```
[[["1", "2"], ["3"]], [[[[["10"]]]], "20"]].
  mapa { |_key, value| value.to_i }
#⇒ [[[1, 2], [3]], [[[[[10]]]], 20]]
```

Comment: We know you, mudsie. "shamelessly" needn't be said.

Comment: The upvote is less for the answer and more because you decided to use the lambda symbol (`λ`) throughout your code base

Comment: @engineermnky lol https://github.com/am-kantox/transdeal we use it in prod.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I predict that many readers of your comment will henceforth incorporate "λ" in their answers, even when inappropriate.

Comment: @CarySwoveland is I were to bite my tongue for fear someone could misinterpret my meaning I'd dare not speak at all.

Comment: @engineersmnky, there is great wisdom in what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
p [["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]].map{|x,y|[x.to_i,y.to_i]}
```

Output

```
[[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to `[["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]].map { |sr| sr.map(&:to_i) }` you'll get the integer values.